# Why the referenced strings are not displayed in swagger-UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Is it possible to describe a simple type (.e.g string or integer) using a reference? I'm using something as below but the issue is that on swagger-ui `errorCode` is displayed as an empty object instead of `string` as in its definition (web.io/dev/api.errorType). So I'm wondering if it's a swagger-ui bug or a specification bug because it passes the schema validation.

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "web.io/api.Error": {
      "properties": {
        "errorCode": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "errorType": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/web.io/dev/api.errorType"
        }
      }
    },
    "web.io/dev/api.errorType": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just a bug. It would be better to just open issues on the github repository than asking the questions here.

Comment: Bug reference: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/243